# how to make UITableView header section editable and number of rows sections also update

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I want to make a app like post so i want that in `UITableView` in header there should be post name given already beside post there should be button comment when that clicked it should open pop to enter comment and that comment be stored in array for that post header
I have post array for header but how to give rows to sections for each they will be given as user comments here is my code

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     NSString *result = [postsArray objectAtIndex:section];

     return result;
}
```

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [headerArray count];// here will be array for each section of header post entered any idea how to use this.
 }
```

Comment: how many sections do you have? In every section you want to header to take comments? And this comments to be shown in particular section rows?

Comment: yes section are in array they will be updated

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `n` number of sections and in every section you want to add elements.
Data structure will be.

**globalVariabls**

```
   int numberOfSections = 3;
    NSMutableArray * arr;
```

In **viewDidLoad**

```
   arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i< numberOfSections; i++)
    {
        [arr addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];   //Each array will contain comments for particular section.
    }
```

In **header** **view** put button which will show a input-box to enter comments. `send section number to that`.
Add that comment in particular array.
eg

```
 -(void)postSubmited:(NSString*)comment inSection:(int)section
{
       //int section = 2; //eg suppose you clicked button in section number 2
       // NSString *comment = @"example"; //get comment for input-box
        NSMutableArray *sectionArr = [arr objectAtIndex:section];
        [sectionArr addObject:comment];
}
```

In **numberOfSections**

```
 return arr.count;
```

In **numberOfRows** method

```
NSMutableArray *sectionArr = [arr objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionArr count];
```

Need to apply similar logic. Try.

Comment: can you please make it more clear i am not getting this you have added method in viewDidLoad each but for post or section there is also another button they get updated and you have written this in viewDidLoad

Comment: About another button and updating it do it on click of submit of input-box. try this and your code. then will tell where you going wrong

Comment: int section = 2; //eg suppose you clicked button in section number 2
    NSString *comment = @"example"; //get comment for input-box
    NSMutableArray *sectionArr = [arr objectAtIndex:section];
    [sectionArr addObject:comment]; where to write this code

Comment: In call back of your input box. In put box should return you string entered by user and section number. So you will add it in particular section arr and call table reloadData method. I have edited answer